# Assembling only JVM part of a Scala.js CrossProject

Tags: scala, scala.js, sbt-assembly

I want to build a fatjar with the sbt assembly PlugIn.

How canI tell the assembly task to take only the JVM part of my project?

My `build.sbt` looks like this (I leave out some irrelevant parts):

```
val example = crossProject.settings(
scalaVersion := "2.11.7",
version := "0.1-SNAPSHOT"
).jsSettings(
   name := "Client"
).jvmSettings(
   Revolver.settings:_*
).jvmSettings(
   name := "Server"
)
val exampleJS = example.js
val exampleJVM = example.jvm.settings(
    (resources in Compile) += {
       (fastOptJS in (exampleJS, Compile)).value
        (artifactPath in (exampleJS, Compile, fastOptJS)).value
    }
)
```

Comment: Why do you want to `assembly` a Scala.js project, in the first place? That does not make any sense to me.

Comment: At least the JVM part has to be deployed to a remote server. My project looks a lot like this [example](https://github.com/lihaoyi/workbench-example-app/tree/autowire/example). Well, I could leave out the JS part at the assembly task, but I didn't manage to find out how to do that. So assembling the whole crossProject seemed like a (poor) alternative for me.

Comment: I totally updated the question. It just makes no sense to include the JS part in the fatjar. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Doesn't `exampleJVM/assembly` do what you want?

Comment: Yep! Thank you! I'm really new to SBT, as you see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As sjrd pointed out, the simple `exampleJVM/assembly`works.